# How do I separate the data in a string where the delimiter character is sometimes not a delimiter?

Tags: vba, excel

## Names

Anita sabarval 90 Female  Nagpur/matheran  17/9  2.0 M Yes
Prabhal jjitu 70 Male Ista/lonavla 8/9 7M no

This is my data in Excel in one cell of each row.

[image: The data format]

```
 Name          age  type     loc             date     sal   given
Anita sabarval  90  Female  Nagpur/matheran 17/9      2m    Yes
Prabhal jjitu   70  Male    sta/lonavla     8/9/201   7M    no
```

The desired output in separate cells of each row.

[image: desired o/p]

```
Note:  
The two part name with space between remains together in one cell  
2.0 M with space between remains together in one cell
```

My attempt so far:

```
Sub ExampleSplit1()
    Selection.TextToColumns _
        Destination:=Range("A2"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:="-"
End Sub
```

[I/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye7XX.png)

[Desired o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BhOJ.png)

Comment: Use Data->Text to Columns

Comment: Need to write a vba code for it and text to columns fails in the name@Tom

Comment: Well show the vba code you have tried so far then. SO isn't a free code writing service

Comment: Sorry @tom Sub ExampleSplit1()
    Selection.TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A2"), _
      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=True, _
      Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, _
      Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, _
      OtherChar:="-"
End Sub

Comment: You might want to use a proper format so it knows how to split, Anita Sabarval contains a space which would be the obvious to split on here, maybe convert it to be CSV(Comma Seperated Values)

Comment: Hi Tanu.  If you need to write code there are a lot of great tutorials that you can find on Google to get you started.  Please check out this [tour] as well as [ask] and [mcve].  Important stuff... good luck!

Comment: @tanu you said `This is my data in excel in one cell` . You have one cell of data?

Comment: @Wisienkas tryed to do that. Still does not work if my automating it

Comment: @ashleedawg I just pasted the code .Thank you

Comment: @ashleedawg yes. It's only in one cell the entire string in A4 and A5

Comment: Why `Space=False`? Try using  `Space:=True, Other:=False`.

Comment: @harun24hr when used that, it puts  the name in different columns

Comment: @Tom    can an instr function be used and the split it

Comment: @Wisienkas can an instr function be used and the split it

Comment: If you have it as CSV excel has a data insert wizard to insert the date. 
Under the tab "Data" you'll fidn the option "From Text/CSV", Should do the trick

Comment: Why not to use regex?

Comment: ([a-z ]+?)\s+(\d+)\s+([a-z]+)\s+([\d-\/]+)\s+([\w ]+) used this but failes when there is another fied added in the middle like nagpur/opts @omegastripes

Comment: @tanu please give more examples with another possible fields added.

Comment: Panjit 17 Male 17/8 nag/megha Coa no
Radhika taruna 18 Femail 18/9 kal/jan+jog ulal No
Yala-ii 18 Femail 18/9 hog/log-opt u32 Yes @omegastripeswant it in this format (panjit)(17)(male) (17/8) (nag/megha) (coa)(no) and (radhika tanura)(18)(femail)(18/9)(kal/jan+jog)(ulal)(no)in excel cells

Comment: @omegastripes can't apse a picture in comments. Apologies

Comment: @tanu Please edit the question to add examples and images. Use proper formatting.

Comment: @omegastripes there is the new image since I can't display it because it's the i/p and desired o/p image

Comment: @tanu What does it mean - i/p, o/p?

Comment: **i/p** is the **raw data** and **o/p** is the **desired output**

Comment: You can click on the hyperlink since 
i/p is the raw data and o/p is the desired output @omegastripes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Here:

using cell A4 as an example,

```
Sub ExampleSplit2()
    Range("A4") = Replace(Range("A4"), " ", "_", 1, 1)
    Range("A4") = Replace(Range("A4"), "  ", " ")
    Range("A4") = Replace(Range("A4"), "  ", " ")
    Range("A4") = Replace(Range("A4"), "  ", " ")
    Range("A4").TextToColumns Range("A4"), , , , , , , True
    Range("A4") = Replace(Range("A4"), "_", " ", 1, 1)
End Sub
```

This will split like this:

[image: ttc-example]

---

### Additional Information:

> <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>M</kbd>  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Text to Columns on Fixed Width would have worked too I guess.  Anyhow, it was kind of frustrating figuring out what you were talking about, please 'Accept' my answer if it's what you wanted.

Comment: thank you. But, the 2M is getting separated into two columns

Comment: Not for me.  Same data, same code. (See image above.)  You must have an extra space in there or something.  Anyhow, this is a place for learning, not for free coding.  Analyze the code I gave you, Google every bit of code piece by piece, and you'll figure it out.  Or if  you don't want to do that, **type `2m` in the cell**.  _(and then push `Enter`.)

Comment: can you please help me , if the last name does not exist. Cause the result is absurd,then

Comment: the date is getting converted after being delimited, could you please help me out with it